# Could not find or load Qt platform plugin "windows"

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt5, pyqt5

I have convert a python file of some pyqt design work to exe. but when i try to run the exe it is showing the message:

> Could not find or load Qt platform plugin "windows".

I can't understand how to solve the problem.

Qt version 5.9 installed in my windows 10 64bit pc & using Python 3.6.1

Comment: How did you convert it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16843303/where-are-qt-platform-dlls-supposed-to-go/16845506#16845506